# How to fetch data from one variable to another

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have applied a inner join query and stored the result in one variable say 'abc'. Now I applied a where clause query and stored it in another variable say 'xyz'. But the issue is I want to put where clause comparing to the data stored in abc. In xyz I want to fetch data from the result stored in abc.

Hope you guys got my point, if don't please do let me know.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

```
$abc = $this->db->query("SELECT Users.firstname, categories.cat_name, 
Products.pname, Requests.sdealer, Requests.sunit, Requests.sdate, 
Requests.sstatus FROM Requests INNER JOIN Users ON 
Requests.sdealer=Users.Id INNER JOIN categories ON 
Requests.scat=categories.cat_id INNER JOIN Products on 
Requests.sproduct=Products.pid");

$xyz = $this->db->query("SELECT Stock.Sunit FROM Stocks WHERE Stock.sdealer 
= (I want data to be fetched through abc)");
```

Comment: may be you need something like where IN()

Comment: What exactly must your `Stock.sdealer` equal? `$abc` holds the resuls of previous query which is not a single value and is not even an one dimentional array of values.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Thanks for the reply. My Stock.sdealer should be equal to the Requests.sdealer of the query used in abc variable

Comment: @SanyamNegi Judging by the  tags you are using CodeIgniter. You should really read up on [DB Reference](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/index.html) especially the part [Getting results](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html). You will have to actually get your desired data from `$abc` and probably construct a `WHERE Stock.sdealer IN(...)` clause instead of `Stock.sdealer 
= (I want data to be fetched through abc)` like Devsi Odedra mentioned. You will have to fill the `IN()` part with the actual data though